# convert a float-like string to float in c

Tags: c, string

I have this code

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  struct timeval current_time;
  gettimeofday(&current_time, NULL);
  printf("seconds : %ld\nmicro seconds : %ld\n",
  current_time.tv_sec, current_time.tv_usec);
  char timestamp[100];
  sprintf(timestamp,"%ld.%ld",current_time.tv_sec,current_time.tv_usec);
  printf("timestamp in char:  %s\n", timestamp);
  float timestamp_f;
  timestamp_f = strtold(timestamp,NULL);
  printf("timestamp in float: %10.6f\n",timestamp_f);
  return 0;
}
```

That returns:

```
seconds : 1615776760
micro seconds : 957945
timestamp in char:  1615776760.957945
timestamp in float: 1615776768.000000
```

What happens to the decimals + the last digit is `8` instead of `0`?

I used `strtof` instead, but still got somewhat similar results:

```
seconds : 1615776930
micro seconds : 767048
timestamp in char:  1615776930.767048
timestamp in float: 1615776896.000000
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're converting the values with high precision, then throwing away that precision by converting the result to a single precision `float`.  Don't use `float`.  Use `double`.

Comment: So I changed the `timestamp_f` to a `double` and the format would be `%lf` instead of `%10.6f`.

Comment: Also `"%ld.%ld"` --> `"%ld.%06ld"`

Comment: `%10.6f` remains OK.  `l` makes no functional difference in printing.

Comment: Don't use `strtof` as float only has 7 significant digits.  You need to use `strtold` but that functio nreturns a `long double` so you need to assign it to a variable of that type.  Change `float timestamp_f;` to `long double timestamp_f;` and make sure your printf specifier is `%10.6Lf` so that printf knows it is a long double.  https://godbolt.org/z/11Tqqo

Answer (score 2):

> What happens to the decimals + the last digit is 8 instead of 0.

`float` lacks precision.  Use `double` or `long double`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your types agree, such as `double` and `strtod` (not `strtold`).  Note that `float` only has ~7 digits of decimal precision while `double` is ~16 decimal digits of precision.

```
double timestamp_f;
timestamp_f = strtod(timestamp,NULL);
```